# python regular expression for "_n1_n2_n1_n3_n1_n1_n2"

Tags: python, regex

Lets say I have the following string,

**My ID is _n1_n2_n1_n3_n1_n1_n2** ,

I'm looking to extract the _n1_n2_n1_n3_n1_n1_n2, we only need to consider word where _n occurs between 5-10 times in a word. the numbers followed by _n anywhere between 0-9.

```
import re
str = 'My ID is _n1_n2_n1_n3_n1_n1_n2'
match = re.search(r'_n\d{0,9}', str)
if match:
    print('found', match.group())
else:
    print('did not find')
```

I was able to extract the **_n1**   with **_n\d{0,9}** but unable to extend further. Can any one help me to extend further in python.

Comment: Quantify it, `r'(?:_n\d{0,9})+'`

Comment: you may want a capture group `(group){n}` (n groups) vs `a{n}` (n a's)

Comment: What exactly do you want to extract ? You're saying you want to extract "_n1_n2_n1_n3_n1_n1_n2" from "_n1_n2_n1_n3_n1_n1_n2", that is just all

Comment: @azro I want to extract _n1_n2_n1_n3_n1_n1_n2 from  My ID is _n1_n2_n1_n3_n1_n1_n2

Comment: Then use `r'(?:_n\d{0,9}){5,10}'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah I extended it {5,10}. Thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what if the string is like  my id is _n1 _n2 _n1 _n4 _n1 _n1 , how about extracting _n1 _n2 _n1 _n4 _n1 _n1 ?

Comment: `_n\d{0,9}(?:\s_n\d{0,9}){4,9}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but how about:

```
(_n\d)+
```

Explanation:

- `(..)` signifies a group
- `+` means we want the group to repeat 1 or more times
- `_n\d` means we want to have `_n` followed by a number

To extract the complete match, we can use regex group `0` which refers to the full match:

```
import re
test_str = 'My ID is _n1_n2_n1_n3_n1_n1_n2'
match = re.search(r'(_n\d)+', test_str)
print(match.group(0))
```

Will output: `_n1_n2_n1_n3_n1_n1_n2`

Comment: what if the string is like my id is _n1 _n2 _n1 _n4 _n1 _n1 , how about extracting _n1 _n2 _n1 _n4 _n1 _n1 ?

Comment: @Ravi - updated to include how you can access the match using `.group(0)`

Answer (score 1):

In Regex, `{0,9}` is not a number between 0 and 9, it's an amount of occurrences for the term that is in front of that, which can be a single character or a group (in parentheses).

If you want single digits from 0 to 9, that is `[0-9]`, which is almost identical to `\d` (but may include non-arabic digits).

So, what you need is either

```regex
(_n[0-9])+
```

or

```regex
(_n\d)+
```

([online](https://regex101.com/r/zXN8DR/1)), where `+` is the number of occurrences from 1 to infinity.

From the comment

> @KellyBundy I mean _n occurs 5-10 times, sorry for wrong phrasing the question.

you can further restrict `+` to be

```regex
(_n\d){5,10}
```

([online](https://regex101.com/r/zXN8DR/2))

As per the comment

> how about extracting _n1 _n2 _n1 _n4 _n1 _n1 ?

you would construct the Regex for an individual part only and use `findall()` like so:

```py
import re
str = 'My ID is _n1_n2_n1_n3_n1_n1_n2'
match = re.findall(r'_n\d', str)
if match:
    print('found', match)
else:
    print('did not find')
```

but if you're not comfortable with Regex so much, you could also try much simpler string operations, e.g.

```py
result = str.split("_n")
print(result[1:])
```

Comment: what if the string is like my id is _n1 _n2 _n1 _n4 _n1 _n1 , how about extracting _n1 _n2 _n1 _n4 _n1 _n1 ?

Answer (score 1):

You need a regex that sees 7 times a `_n\d` : `'(_n\d){7}'`

```
match = re.search(r'(_n\d){7}', value)
```

---

- `(_n\d){4,8}` for range of amount
- `(_n\d)+` for any amount

Comment: what if the string is like my id is _n1 _n2 _n1 _n4 _n1 _n1 , how about extracting _n1 _n2 _n1 _n4 _n1 _n1 ?

Comment: @Ravi then learn about regex to modify it yourself. if i get it it's a space between each so `(\s?_n\d){7}`